# Sql server: limit string_agg result

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I have the following query (showing for each customer the list of users):

```
select cu.customer_id , STRING_AGG(u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name , ',') as users   
from customer_user cu join user u on cu.user_id = u.id   
where ... 
group by cu.customer_id
```

How can I limit the string_agg function to aggregate only 10 elements for each group?

Comment: The first 10 users for each customer, i don't care the order of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to number the rows:

```
SELECT customer_id , STRING_AGG(first_name + ' ' + last_name , ',') AS users   
FROM (
   SELECT 
      cu.customer_id, u.first_name, u.last_name,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cu.customer_id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
   FROM customer_user cu 
   JOIN user u ON cu.user_id = u.id
   -- WHERE ...
) t
WHERE rn <= 10
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Again this is another case where I find separating the "ugly" part of the logic (concatenation and determining "first" or "any" 10) in a CTE, then not aggregating until after:

```
; -- see sqlblog.org/cte
WITH src AS
(
  SELECT cu.customer_id, n = CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name),
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY @@SPID)
    FROM dbo.customer_user AS cu
    INNER JOIN dbo.[user] AS u -- bad table name
    ON cu.user_id = u.id
    /* WHERE ... */
)
SELECT customer_id, users = STRING_AGG(n, N',')
  FROM src
  WHERE rn <= 10
  GROUP BY customer_id;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0be9164e44d7bf9ff8dd85f2df862ba)

Answer (score 0):

We can use row_number in a sub-query. I have limited to 2 in this example and you can change the limit for rn as to 10, or other number.
I show the first query without a limit and the second with a limit to show the difference.

> ```
> create table users(
>   id int, 
>   first_name varchar(25),
>   last_name varchar(25)
>   );
> insert into users values
> (1,'Andrew','A'),
> (2,'Bill','B'),
> (3,'Charlie','C');
> create table customer_user(
>   customer_id int,
>   user_id int);
> insert into customer_user values
> (1,1),(1,2),(1,3);
> GO
> ```

6 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select 
>   cu.customer_id , 
>   STRING_AGG(u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name , ',') as users   
> from customer_user cu join users u on cu.user_id = u.id  
> group by cu.customer_id
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> customer_id | users                    
> ----------: | :------------------------
>           1 | Andrew A,Bill B,Charlie C
> ```

> ```
> select
>   u.customer_id , 
>   STRING_AGG(u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name , ',') as users   
> from (
>   select
>     row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by u.id) rn,
>     cu.customer_id,
>     u.first_name,
>     u.last_name
>   from customer_user cu 
>   join users u on cu.user_id = u.id  
>   ) u
> where rn < 3
> group by u.customer_id
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> customer_id | users          
> ----------: | :--------------
>           1 | Andrew A,Bill B
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5d10eec636d67e8294ef057fceddd373)*